# How to remove spaces and add enter in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to remove spaces in the following code. or you can see in https://jsfiddle.net/m2rn2nqg/9/

```
<br> ...... THIS RESULT ...... <br> 
 <div id="posttextareadisplay"></div>
 <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span16">
        <textarea class="isi" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" style="height:80px;width:300px;" name="mytxtarea" id="mytxtarea" class="ed">This is a sample text










فَإِذَا جَلَسْتَ فِي وَسَطِ الصَّلَاةِ فَاطْمَئِنَّ، وَافْتَرِشْ فَخِذَكَ الْيُسْرَى ثُمَّ تَشَهَّدْ
</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<br> ___________________THIS CODE __________________<br> 
 <pre id="postcode"><pre>
<br>_____________________________________________________

<script>
$('.tools').on("click", function() {
        var gogel = $('.isi').val();
        $('#posttextareadisplay').html(arabicParagraph(gogel, arabic => `<p class="lbs0">${ arabic }</p>`));
        $('#postcode').text(arabicParagraph(gogel, arabic => `<p class="lbs0">${ arabic }</p>`));
     });
    $('.isi').on("input propertychange", function() {
        var gogel = $('.isi').val();
        $('#posttextareadisplay').html(arabicParagraph(gogel, arabic => `<p class="lbs0">${ arabic }</p>`));
        $('#postcode').text(arabicParagraph(gogel, arabic => `<p class="lbs0">${ arabic }</p>`));
    });

const additionalCustomizationText = pattern => customization => text => customization(text, pattern)
function arabicParagraph(text, cb) {
    text = text.trim()
    const arabicFontPattern = /[\u0600-\u06ff]|[\u0750-\u077f]|[\ufb50-\ufc3f]|[\ufe70-\ufefc]/g
    const getArabicText = additionalCustomizationText(arabicFontPattern)
    const addArabicParagraphAndBold = getArabicText((text, pattern) => {
        text = text.trim()
        if (pattern.test(text) && !/[\w!@#$%^&*-_.,<>?`~\|]/g.test(text)) {
            return cb(text)
        } else if (text === '') {
            return ''
        }
        return `<p>${text.replace(/(\s+[\u0600-\u06ED]+|[\u0750-\u077f]+|[\ufb50-\ufc3f]+|[\ufe70-\ufefc]+(?:\s+[\u0600-\u06ED]+|[\u0750-\u077f]+|[\ufb50-\ufc3f]+|[\ufe70-\ufefc]+)*)/g, '<o>$1</o>')}</p>`
    })
    const getTextEveryLine = text.trim().split('\n\n')
    return getTextEveryLine.reduce((res, val) => res + addArabicParagraphAndBold(val), '')
}

</script>
```

**Question 1 ====  SOLVED  ====**

Try typing 1 letter ***This is a sample text*** to generate the result and the code. Why there are still excessive spaces `<p>         </p>`, because I already use `$.trim()`? So if it's just a space, no need to create paragraphs

**Question 2**

Take a look at the second part of the problem. I want to add `<br>` if there is only 1 enter.  Because if I use the current code, the result is the same as the first code. Just add space only, NOT enter or `<br>`. So like if no enter give space, if any one enter give enter and any two or more, It will separate from the paragraph

```
/* If no enter <---- this no problem */ 
This is a sample text فَإِذَا جَلَسْتَ فِي وَسَطِ الصَّلَاةِ فَاطْمَئِنَّ، وَافْتَرِشْ فَخِذَكَ الْيُسْرَى ثُمَّ تَشَهَّدْ
/* To be */
<p>This is a sample text<o> فَإِذَا</o><o> جَلَسْتَ</o><o> فِي</o><o> وَسَطِ</o><o> الصَّلَاةِ</o><o> فَاطْمَئِنَّ،</o><o> وَافْتَرِشْ</o><o> فَخِذَكَ</o><o> الْيُسْرَى</o><o> ثُمَّ</o><o> تَشَهَّدْ</o></p>



/* If JUST 1 enter <---- this PROBLEM */ 
This is a sample text 
فَإِذَا جَلَسْتَ فِي وَسَطِ الصَّلَاةِ فَاطْمَئِنَّ، وَافْتَرِشْ فَخِذَكَ الْيُسْرَى ثُمَّ تَشَهَّدْ
/* RESULT */
<p>This is a sample text<o> 
فَإِذَا</o><o> جَلَسْتَ</o><o> فِي</o><o> وَسَطِ</o><o> الصَّلَاةِ</o><o> فَاطْمَئِنَّ،</o><o> وَافْتَرِشْ</o><o> فَخِذَكَ</o><o> الْيُسْرَى</o><o> ثُمَّ</o><o> تَشَهَّدْ</o></p>
/* But i want to be */
<p>This is a sample text<br><o> 
فَإِذَا</o><o> جَلَسْتَ</o><o> فِي</o><o> وَسَطِ</o><o> الصَّلَاةِ</o><o> فَاطْمَئِنَّ،</o><o> وَافْتَرِشْ</o><o> فَخِذَكَ</o><o> الْيُسْرَى</o><o> ثُمَّ</o><o> تَشَهَّدْ</o></p>



/* If JUST 2 enter or more <---- this no problem */ 
This is a sample text

فَإِذَا جَلَسْتَ فِي وَسَطِ الصَّلَاةِ فَاطْمَئِنَّ، وَافْتَرِشْ فَخِذَكَ الْيُسْرَى ثُمَّ تَشَهَّدْ
/* To be */
<p>This is a sample text</p><p class="lbs0">فَإِذَا جَلَسْتَ فِي وَسَطِ الصَّلَاةِ فَاطْمَئِنَّ، وَافْتَرِشْ فَخِذَكَ الْيُسْرَى ثُمَّ تَشَهَّدْ</p>
```

Update : **Mohammad Ahmad**

Your code to be like this

```
<p>This is a samaple text<br /><br />          <br /><br />         <br /><br /><br /><br />          <br /><br /><br />فَإِذَا جَلَسْتَ فِي وَسَطِ الصَّلَاةِ فَاطْمَئِنَّ، وَافْتَرِشْ فَخِذَكَ الْيُسْرَى ثُمَّ تَشَهَّدْ<br /></p>
```

Not like this, i just need one `<br>` if any ONE ENTER `\n`

```
<p>This is a sample text<br><o> 
فَإِذَا</o><o> جَلَسْتَ</o><o> فِي</o><o> وَسَطِ</o><o> الصَّلَاةِ</o><o> فَاطْمَئِنَّ،</o><o> وَافْتَرِشْ</o><o> فَخِذَكَ</o><o> الْيُسْرَى</o><o> ثُمَّ</o><o> تَشَهَّدْ</o></p>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lrput04L/

Comment: Make it undefined

Answer (score 0):

you can use ReGex to replace spaces and tabs. after assigning gogel variable:

```
 var gogel = $('.isi').val();
```

Add this line:

```
 gogel = gogel.replace(/[\t\s]{2,}/i, ' ');
```

Question 2:

```
$('.isi').on("input propertychange", function() {
    var gogel = $('.isi').val();
    gogel = gogel.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
    $('#posttextareadisplay').html(
    arabicParagraph(gogel, arabic => `<p class="lbs0">${ arabic }</p>`));
    $('#postcode').text(
    arabicParagraph(gogel, arabic => `<p class="lbs0">${ arabic }</p>`));
});
```

Comment: Not help, thats make broken funcion

Comment: If using that code, <p class="lbs0">${ arabic }</p> not working

Comment: Can you answer?

Comment: Please review updated answer. there is something wired. when i wrote something in arabic. i got the <o> tags around each word. idk if this your what you are attend  to do or not.

Comment: It makes the function arabicParagraph, not working. I think we must change `text.trim().split('\n\n')`. but i dont how

Comment: i don't know what you are trying to achieve but however please check the code at https://jsfiddle.net/nqdb2pu1/ . is that what you are looking for ? if not, please give more explanation of what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Update questions